# Laravel Eloquent, apply select on my queries in whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here my code :

```
$prestations = Prestation::with('service','facility','conciergeries.network')
            ->whereHas('service', function ($query) use ($searchService) {
                $query->addSelect('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchService/i");
            })  
            ->whereHas('facility', function ($query) use ($searchPartenaire) {
                $query->addSelect('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchPartenaire/i");
            })
            ->whereHas('conciergeries.network', function ($query) use ($searchFiliale) {
                $query->addSelect('id','name')->where('name', 'regexp', "/$searchFiliale/i");
            })
                ->where('name', 'regexp', "/$search/i")
                ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderDirection)
                ->paginate(50);
```

I want get only names and ids of "service", "facility" and "conciegeries.network".
I tried to use `select('id','name');` and `select(['id','name']);` or `addSelect('id','name');` and `pluck('id', 'name');` but i get all datas.
Do you have alternatives solutions ?
Thank you !

Comment: I think the selects need to be inside of `with`, not `whereHas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select needs to be added to `with`, not `whereHas`. Try this instead:

```
Prestation::with(['service' => function($query) { $query->select(['id','name']);},
    'facility' => function($query) { $query->select(['id','name']);},
    'conciergeries.network' => function($query) { $query->select(['id','name']);}
])
```